# Colima et docker registry

Tags: docker, homebrew, colima

I've got a problem with my registry config.
I installed colima et docker thanks to brew

I set the configuration colima with my mirror registry and I find it in my docker config, but it still go on the `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/`
and so I get this error `Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/`

The only difference with my colleague is that the docker config does'nt notice the
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
How I can force it?
Any idea why docker doesn't care about my Registry Mirrors?

Thank you